# Valores de sessão não aparecem

Tags: php

Cada utilizador tem um login com `email` e `senha`.

Eu consigo entrar e receber os valores de sessão do utilizador, como o `username` e a `idade`.

Em outras contas de utilizador, após o login `success`, não recebo qualquer valor das variáveis de sessão, mas se fizer um  `Print_r ($_SESSION);` consigo ver que existem dados nas `$_SESSION`.  Alguma dica?

Na base de dados os utilizadores estão corretos.

**login.php**

```
<?php 
include('init.php');
$em = $_POST['txtemail'];
$pw = $_POST['txtpassword'];


$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste', 'teste', 'teste'); 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select * from user where email = :email and senha =    :senha'); 

$stmt->execute(array(
   ":email" => $em,
   ":senha" => $pw,
));
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
$linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$_SESSION['email']=$linha['email'];
$_SESSION['username']=$linha['username'];
$_SESSION['id']=$linha['id'];
$_SESSION['last_login']=$linha['last_login'];
$_SESSION['nlog']=$linha['nlog'];

header("location: ../portal/index.php");
}
else //CASO NÃO COINCIDAM
{

header("location: ../index.php?erro=1");
}



?>
```

**init.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

//CONN DB
include('conn.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['start_login'])) { 
 $_SESSION['start_login'] = time(); 
 // adiciona 30 segundos ao tempo e grava em outra variável de sessão
 $_SESSION['logout_time'] = $_SESSION['start_login'] + 30*60; 

}
// se o tempo atual for maior que o tempo de logout
if(time() >= $_SESSION['logout_time']) { 
header("location:php/logout.php"); //vai para logout

} else {
 $red = $_SESSION['logout_time'] - time(); // tempo que falta
 //echo "Início de sessão: ".$_SESSION['start_login']."<br>";
 //echo "Redirecionando em ".$red." segundos.<br>";
}
?>
```

No topo das páginas reservadas tenho:

```
<?php 
include('php/init.php'); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) //SE n EXISTIR AUTENTICAÇÃO
{
header("location: ../index.php?erro=1");
}
//Print_r ($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: O que `var_dump($_SESSION)` exibe (após autenticar)?

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, mas tem uma série de problemas  básicos no seu código que eu sugeriria arrumar antes de mais nada: primeiro, usar senha aberta direto no DB, outra é o sistema totalmente aberto para SQL Injection, qualquer um apaga seu DB inteiro com facilidade da forma que está. Outra coisa é que faltam os die() depois de todos os header location. Fora isso, o header do location está malformado. Até funciona assim, mas só por que o browser faz um "esforço" pra interpretar. São pequenos detalhes, mas não deixar este tipo de coisa passar é um dos requisitos de um profissional.

Comment: Para boa parte dos problemas mencionados tem respostas no site, seria legal dar uma lida, e qualquer dúvida, deixar um comentário ou questão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento as variaveis de sessão username, id, email

Comment: Mas o var_dump exibe exatamente o que?

Comment: Com o var_dump consigo ver os valores todos da sessão.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado pelas dicas, pude corrigir a ligação à base de dados. Numa outra altura irei rever os `header location`

Comment: @DavidConcha o header é fácil, basta acertar espaços, maiúsculas e minúsculas, e usar as variáveis do PHP para montar o caminho completo: `Location: //seusite.com/caminho/` - evite caminhos relativos. Sobre injection, tem soluções aqui no site mesmo. Procure por Injection ou _prepared statements_ que vai achar uns exemplos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que você for requisitar algum dado da sessão você deve dar um `session_start()` antes. Ex:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   header("Location:index.php?error=denied");
}
```

Seja que você for autenticar, recuperar um dado da sessão, altera-lo ou mesmo destruir a sessão, antes você deve utilizar o método `session_start()` em todas as páginas que você for utilizar os dados da sessão

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, o ficheiro init.php já contem o `session_start()`